# three.js Could not clone a line

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm new to three and recently I ran into a problem.
Everytime I wanted to clone a line I would get this exception. **Cannot read property 'r' of undefined**. Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem? I appreciate you help.
Here is my code:

```js
const basicGeometry = new (THREE.BufferGeometry as any)()
const basicMaterial = this.generateShaderMaterial({ transparent: true, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, linewidth: 1 })
const basicLine = new THREE.Line(basicGeometry, basicMaterial)
const line = basicLine.clone()
```

Comment: What is the source for `this.generateShaderMaterial(…)`?

Comment: You haven't declared any attributes in your `BufferGeometry`! You need to at least have two vertices to know the line's starting and ending positions. I recommend you at least try to read the documentation: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

Comment: yeah....that was the problem. I should have read the doc more carefully. Sorry and thank you so much. @Marquizzo

Comment: It is just a function generating a shader material and  has nothing to do with my problem, and Marquizzo solved my problem perfectly. Thank you for your attention. @Li357